# How to fix issue with Late in flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart, void

I have this code in flutter

```
late String firstHalf;
  late String secondHalf;

  bool hiddenText = true;
  double textHeight = Diamension.screenHeight / 5.63;

  @override
  void iniState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.text.length > textHeight) {
      firstHalf = widget.text.substring(0, textHeight.toInt());
      secondHalf =
          widget.text.substring(textHeight.toInt() + 1, widget.text.length);
    } else {
      firstHalf = widget.text;
      secondHalf = "";
    }
  }
```

from the code you will see that I initialized "secondHalf" but I kept getting this error in debug

```
Exception has occurred.
LateError (LateInitializationError: Field 'secondHalf' has not been initialized.)
```

Comment: You should get a warning about `iniState` is not overriding any method which is because you have a spelling mistake. It is called `initState`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you copy-pasted wrong into StackOverflow, you have just missed a `t`...

Try changing `void iniState() {` to `void initState() {`

You probably have this warning (as also noted by @julemand101):

> The method doesn't override an inherited method. Try updating this
> class to match the superclass, or removing the override
> annotation.dartoverride_on_non_overriding_member

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
void iniState()
```

with

```
void initState()
```